# Record video using mediarcorder in background making mutiple files of each 10 seconds while recording is going on in front end

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I wand a simple activity that start recording and while recording is going simultaneously it will save multiple video files of 10 seconds up to stop recording if anyone have an example please share it will help me a lot  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use context object to call openOrCreateDatabase :

```
db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("MY_App_Data",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```